# In dplyr, is it possible to specify where to add a new column using mutate?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Currently I have to use `add_column` to directly insert a new column into a desired position, or use `mutate`, then `select` with the new desired column order.

```
mips.group <- str_extract(mips.manifest$PlateName, "[:alnum:]+_([[:alnum:]&&[^P]]+(_CL)?)?|(KORgex)")

mips.manifest %<>%
  add_column(MIPSGroup=mips.group, .after="PlateName")
```

Is it possible to directly tell `mutate` where to add the new column, and if not, is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the code of mutate, it appears it wouldn't be easy since eventually it dives into a C-function:

```
> mutate
function (.data, ...) 
{
    UseMethod("mutate")
}
<environment: namespace:dplyr>
> methods(mutate)
[1] mutate.data.frame* mutate.default*    mutate.tbl_df*    
see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
> getAnywhere(mutate.tbl_df)
A single object matching ‘mutate.tbl_df’ was found
It was found in the following places
  registered S3 method for mutate from namespace dplyr
  namespace:dplyr
with value

function (.data, ...) 
{
    dots <- named_quos(...)
    mutate_impl(.data, dots)
}
<environment: namespace:dplyr>
> mutate_impl
Error: object 'mutate_impl' not found
> getAnywhere(mutate_impl)
A single object matching ‘mutate_impl’ was found
It was found in the following places
  namespace:dplyr
with value

function (df, dots) 
{
    .Call(`_dplyr_mutate_impl`, df, dots)
}
<environment: namespace:dplyr>
```

Seems doubtful that modifications will be welcomed since you already have a workable solution.

Answer (score 2):

There is a feature request on the github page of dplyr regarding this question. You can read about this [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2047). But for now it is left as is.

But you can always add your reasons to the discussion.